# IOS subtracting from programmatically made labels and steppers

Tags: ios, uistepper

I'm making an ipad application for ticket sales, and i have a problem when i want to subtract..

The UI is made like so:

```
  for(NSString *string in ticketArray){

    float y = 60*ticketCount+spaceFloat;

    //subView to contain one ticket
    UIView *ticketTypeView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, y, 1000, 60)];
    if(ticketCount%2){
    ticketTypeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:ticketTypeView];

    //label for ticket type name
    UILabel *ticketType = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, 500, 50)];
    [ticketType setText:string];
    [ticketType setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica neue" size:20.0]];
    [ticketTypeView addSubview:ticketType];


    //UIStepper for ticket amount
    UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 16, 0, 0)];
    stepper.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);
    [stepper addTarget:self action:@selector(chanegestep:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    stepper.maximumValue = 100;
    stepper.minimumValue = 0;
    [ticketTypeView addSubview:stepper];

    //label for price pr. ticket
    UILabel *pricePrTicket = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(620, 5, 100, 50)];
    [pricePrTicket setText:@"1000.50"];
    pricePrTicket.tag = kTagPriceTicket;
    [ticketTypeView addSubview:pricePrTicket];

    //totalPrice label
    UILabel *totalTypePrice = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(900, 5, 100, 50)];
    [totalTypePrice setText:@"0.00 Kr."];
    totalTypePrice.tag = kTagTotalTypePrice;
    [ticketTypeView addSubview:totalTypePrice];

    ticketCount++;
}
```

}

my ValueChanged method:

```
 - (IBAction) chanegestep:(UIStepper *)sender {
double va = [sender value];
NSLog(@"stepper pressed");


//get the 2 labels for the price and for displaying price
UILabel *ticketprice = (UILabel *)[sender.superview viewWithTag:kTagPriceTicket];
UILabel *totalPrice = (UILabel *)[sender.superview viewWithTag:kTagTotalTypePrice];
double price = [ticketprice.text doubleValue];



//calc the total from that one ticet type
double totalDisplayed = va*price;

//add to the complete sales amount
completeSalesAmount += totalDisplayed;


NSLog(@"%.02f",completeSalesAmount);
if(ticketprice){
    totalPrice.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.02fKr.",totalDisplayed];
}

//activate btnContinue
if(completeSalesAmount!=0){
    [btnContinue setEnabled:YES];
}




//[ setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)va]];
```

}

My problem: adding up the numbers works fine ofc, but when the "-" on the stepper is pressed i have to detect that somehow, and subtract the price for the given ticket from the totalSalesAmount..

Any help is appreciated.

Regards, an up and coming IOS dev xD

edit:

the completedSalesAmount is calculated every time valueChanged is called..

so lets say i have 2 ticket types, and there is 1 selected of each.

ticket1 - price 10$ - amount 1, total 10$ (10*1)

completeSalesAmount - 0 += (10*1) = 10$

ticket2 - price 10$ - amount 1, total 10$ (10*1)

completeSalesAmount - 10 += (10*1) = 20$

now "-" is pressed on ticket1

ticket1 - price 10$ - amount 0, total 0$ (10*0)

completeSalesAmount += 0...

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your issue. When you press "-" your `[sender value]` will decrease, can't you work with that ?

Comment: edited question, hope it enlightens my needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't know which button is pressed on the stepper. What you could do is subclass your UIStepper like this post suggests :

[UIStepper. Find out whether incremented or decremented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813816/uistepper-find-out-whether-incremented-or-decremented)

Otherwise you can make a function to calculate `completeSalesAmount` with every UIStepper, you will need to put your UIStepper wrappers in an array :

```
NSMutableArray *fullSteppers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[ticketArray count]];    

for(NSString *string in ticketArray){
    ...
    stepper.tag = kTagStepper;
    [fullSteppers addObject:ticketTypeView];
    ...
}

- (void)updateCompleteSalesAmount{
    completeSalesAmount = 0;
    for(UIView *fullStepper in fullSteppers){
        UILabel *ticketprice = (UILabel *)[fullStepper viewWithTag:kTagPriceTicket];
        UILabel *totalPrice = (UILabel *)[fullStepper viewWithTag:kTagTotalTypePrice];
        double price = [ticketprice.text doubleValue];

        UIStepper *stepper = (UIStepper *)[fullStepper viewWithTag:kTagStepper];
        completeSalesAmount += stepper.value * price;
    }
}
```

And just call the update function in your changestep method :

```
- (IBAction) chanegestep:(UIStepper *)sender {
    ....
    [self updateCompleteSalesAmount];
}
```

Comment: exept.. how do i access the price of the given ticket?